# Custom api gateway websocket endpoint using serverless

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I’m trying to custom my api gateway websocket endpoint via serverless because I need to initialize it for cloudfront which is deployed before websocket.
The initialize code is below:

```
ApiGatewayWebsocketApi: 
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.variant}-WebsocketApi
        ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
        RouteSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
        Description: "WebSocket API for ${self:provider.variant}"
```

And I exported it as an output:

```
ApiGatewayWebsocketApiId:
          Value: 
            Ref: ApiGatewayWebsocketApi
          Export:
            Name: ${self:custom.configFile.appCode}-${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.variant}-ApiGatewayWebsocketApiId
```

Then ApiGatewayWebsocketApiId will represent an endpoint string like `b6hnpuyzq6`

And I can get it in websocket serverless.yml:

```
 WebSocketApiId:
    Fn::ImportValue: ${self:custom.configFile.appCode}-${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.variant}-ApiGatewayWebsocketApiId
```

But here is the problem:
how can I import it to my function such as connectionHandler so that this websocket can use the endpoint imported above:

```
  connectionHandler:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.variant}-${self:custom.configFile.appCode}-ws-connection
    handler: WebsocketTestHandler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
      - websocket:
          route: $disconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to pass `WebSocketApiId` parameter value trough `WEB_SOCKET_API_ID` environment variable available in the handler, like this:

```
  connectionHandler:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.variant}-${self:custom.configFile.appCode}-ws-connection
    handler: WebsocketTestHandler
    environment:
      WEB_SOCKET_API_ID:
        Ref: WebSocketApiId
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
      - websocket:
          route: $disconnect
```